# Finish sending media from Android to Chromecast. (Back to chromecast home-screen)

Tags: android, chromecast, android-cast-api

I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender#joining-sessions) Google Developers tutorial and I have written my Android Sender with the Media Chanel to send my songs to chromecast.

The app works well but, when I want to stop the connection,(every time I call teardown() method) my apps logo still appears in my TV background for few minutes before to show the default chromecast "home-screen".

If I "Stop Sending" from Chrome browser tab, the app finish well and the chromecast default wallpapers appears in the TV inmediately. How can i recreated this programaticaly from android ?

Is not the default behavior when you call to...

```
  Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(mApiClient, mSessionId);
```

...??

Comment: Are you using the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)? If not, you should consider doing so. I believe it handles disconnect in [BastCastManager](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/android/libraries/cast/companionlibrary/cast/BaseCastManager.java) so you can refer to that as a reference, if anything.

Comment: No, Im not. I'll have a look. Is an easy way to import it with Gradle ?

Comment: You can import the project into Android studio or reference it. The [CastVideos-android sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/build.gradle) would be a good reference, since it goes hand in hand with the CCL.

Comment: Finally I add CCL as a Module dependency and yes, all this matters seems to be cleaner with this library.